# Screen is broken when another window is displayed on top of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

While using Visual Studio Code, the screen is broken as shown in the following gif.
[image: The process of screen breakage]

It is not visible in the gif file, but is being dragged with the another window open.

The same thing did not happen in other programs (e.g., visual studio community, source tree, etc.). 
It also happened on other monitors connected to internal graphics cards.

When scrolling in vscode, the same symptoms occur in the parts that are not scrolling (such as the left menu section).

Comment: try to reinstall it !!!

Comment: Your description is quite contradictory. You wrote : "as shown in the following gif" and "It is not visible in the gif". And to be honest, I don't understand your problem after reading the description three times while I'm using Visual Studio everyday.

Comment: I reinstalled but it is the same :(

Comment: "not visible" means that no other window floating above the vscode was recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the graphics card driver(geforce) fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

go to your vs code shortcut properties and add at the end of the path "--disable-gpu" example like these: "C:\Users\your-user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --disable-gpu