# Visual Studio Code acts weird

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code showing this weird screen I don't know how to fix it and It is very annoying
It only appears in the programs. I have 2 monitors and it acted the same.

Sorry for my bad English.
[image]

Comment: Looks related to: [Screen is broken when another window is displayed on top of vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60771833/2745495). Though, the OP there fixed it by updating graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

1.Reinstall the Visual Studio Code

2.[click here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/errors) to clarify your error